# how do I use simple_html_dom with phantomjs

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs, simple-html-dom, php-phantomjs

I am trying to get those two libraries to work with each other my current code looks like this:

> phantomjs.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');
var address = system.args[1]; 
page.open(address, function () {
    var content = page.content;
    console.log(content);
    phantom.exit();
 });
```

> scraper.php

```
exec('phantomjs assets/phantomjs.js '.$page, $output);
$html2 = str_get_html($output);
```

What I get back is this:

```
Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 91

Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 1139

Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 1149

Warning: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 1620

Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 1632

Warning: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 1620

Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 1632

Warning: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 1620

Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 1632

Warning: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 1620

Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 1632

Warning: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 1620

Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 1632

Warning: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 1620

Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 1632

Warning: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 1620

Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 1632

Warning: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 1620

Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 1632

Warning: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 1620

Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\assets\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 1632
```

simple_html_dom function that is returning the error:

```
// remove noise from html content
// save the noise in the $this->noise array.
protected function remove_noise($pattern, $remove_tag=false)
{
    global $debugObject;
    if (is_object($debugObject)) { $debugObject->debugLogEntry(1); }

    $count = preg_match_all($pattern, $this->doc, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER|PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    for ($i=$count-1; $i>-1; --$i)
    {
        $key = '___noise___'.sprintf('% 5d', count($this->noise)+1000);
        if (is_object($debugObject)) { $debugObject->debugLog(2, 'key is: ' . $key); }
        $idx = ($remove_tag) ? 0 : 1;
        $this->noise[$key] = $matches[$i][$idx][0];
        $this->doc = substr_replace($this->doc, $key, $matches[$i][$idx][1], strlen($matches[$i][$idx][0]));
    }

    // reset the length of content
    $this->size = strlen($this->doc);
    if ($this->size>0)
    {
        $this->char = $this->doc[0];
    }
}
```

When I use `var_dump($output)` I get the html of the site so I know the command is working but simple_html_dom does not seem to accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is this: `$output` is array, but `str_get_html` expects a string as argument. So make sure you convert $output to string before parsing it.

Comment: it turned out this is the answer. putting this: `$output = implode(' ',$output);` before `str_get_html` solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$body = `phantomjs myscript.js`;
$doc = str_get_html($body);
```

You might need a setTimeout in the phantomjs script, you're not giving a lot of time for the dom to load.

Comment: Look at ‘scraper.php’ I have the exact same code that you provided

Comment: Try it with backticks. Backticks work the same way in every script language.